# How to add Adsense code to child theme

Tags: adsense

Google Adsense requires its activation code to be pasted right after the `<head>` tag of a site.

However, I'm using a WordPress child theme.

How can I paste my Google Adsense code in a child theme?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily put your Google Adsense code within the `<head>` element of your WordPress site by using either of these methods in your `functions.php` file or by creating a plugin for that purpose:

```
/**
 * Load my Google Adsense code.
 *
 * Here, your Google Adsense Code is stored within in your plugins directory, under the
 * the file named: gads.js, which contains your Google Adsense Code.
 * The full file path for the purpose below: wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-name/inc/gads.js
 */
function load_my_google_adsense_code() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gads', plugins_url('/inc/gads.js', __FILE__), null, '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_google_adsense_code' );
```

Alternatively, you can include it directly as part of your function as below;

```
/**
 * Load my Google Adsense code.
 *
 * Here, your Google Adsense Code is contained directly in your function.
 */
function load_my_google_adsense_code() {
    ?>
        <script>
            // Your Google Adsense Code here.
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'load_my_google_adsense_code');
```

*Please note:*

The two (2) approaches above will enable you to have your Google Adsense code within the `<head>` element of your WordPress site, usually right before `</head>`, but this is really theme dependent as it depends on the placement of the `wp_head()` hook within the `header.php`.

Its generally recommended to have the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` declaration before the `</head>` which explains the point above, purposely to avoid potential conflicts with plugins among others and implemented as below:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 * File name: header.php
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Other contents here -->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
    <!-- Other contents may follow -->
```

As such, the options provided above will work as *Google Adsense requires, per your OP*, should your the `wp_head()` hook of your theme satisfy that condition: occurring right below your `<head>` element.

Should that not be the case and you still need to achieve this as *Google Adsense requires*, you will need to directly edit your `header.php` file for that purpose, either:

1- Putting the `wp_head()` hook right after your `<head>` element as in:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 * File name: header.php
 */

?<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <!-- Other contents here -->
```

*In the above example, you will have to use either of the earlier two enumerated approaches above so as to leverage on this edit in order to achieve your goal.*

or

2- Pasting your code directly in your `header.php` file, right after your `<head>` element as in:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 * File name: header.php
 */

?<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Your Google Adsense code here, right after the <head> element -->
    <!-- Other contents here -->
```

*Always remember to back up your files before doing such edits.*

Answer (score -1):

Use wp_head hook in functions.php

```
add_action('wp_head','add_adsense');
```

Comment: this might be the correct answer, but it is very hard to understand how exactly to use it (for example what is add_adsense). Please edit it and add all the parts required to actually make it work or at least to understand how to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_google_adsense_code' );
function add_google_adsense_code() {
?><script>
// Your Google Adsense Code here.
</script><?php        
}
```

See [action hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Added to your child themes functions file, this hook fires after wp_head therefore printing your script after the closing `</head>` tag.